# How to set deafult value of django form select field in template?

Tags: django, django-views

How to set deafult value of django form select field in template?

How to set deafult value of django form select field in template?

Comment: How to ask questions? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can do this way:

```
<select id="ip_addr">
    {% for host in hosts %}
        <option value="{{ host.ipaddress }}" {% if forloop.first %}selected{% endif %}>{{ host.ipaddress }}</option> #here default value will be first value from for loop
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

This is the way you can do